# Running MariaDB Galera Cluster on my dev machine fails

Tags: debian, mariadb, galera

I am struggling to get a MariaDB Galera cluster running on my Debian 7 machine. I am trying to setup a cluster with two nodes both running on Debian 7.

When I first install Galera I can run it find. Then I add the following to /etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
#wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=32G"

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.196.196,192.168.196.197"

# Galera Synchronization Congifuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
#wsrep_sst_auth=user:pass

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="192.168.196.196"
wsrep_node_name="db1"
```

Unfortunately, when trying to start the server after adding the above config using `sudo service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster`, it fails to start. I get the following error in the syslog:

```
Nov 20 12:21:11 db1 /etc/init.d/mysql[22455]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Nov 20 12:21:11 db1/etc/init.d/mysql[22455]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Nov 20 12:21:11 db1 /etc/init.d/mysql[22455]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)'
Nov 20 12:21:11 db1 /etc/init.d/mysql[22455]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

Does anyone know what might cause this or how I can fix it? I got it working fine on a different machine running Debian 7. I've tried completely uninstalling and re-installing MariaDB Galera and starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

strace the process (i.e. run 'strace mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster'). What you're most likely discover is that the process will die quite immediate - in the end, it's a missing shared library => libgalera_smm.so.

Thus:

wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

most likely causes your issue (at least I had the same issue on a fresh debian7 install with the recent packages). I am using 10.0.14 btw.